# WPF unable to bind rectangle background image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create rectangle with dynamic background image but it somehow wont work. I am not sure if its problem with some types or bindings as its my first binding in life.

Crete new instance of my custom control

```
        BitmapImage image = new(new Uri(@filePath));
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush(image);
        InputBlock inputBlock = new()
        {
            Height= image.Height + 20,
            Width= image.Width,
            ImageBrush = imageBrush
        };
```

my cs

```
    public partial class InputBlock : UserControl
    {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageBrushProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ImageBrush", typeof(ImageBrush), 
         typeof(InputBlock),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ImageBrush ImageBrush
    {
        get { return (ImageBrush)GetValue(ImageBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageBrushProperty, value); }
    }


        public InputBlock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
```

in xaml

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="ImageRectangle" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="{Binding ImageBrush}" Width="500" Height="500">
    </Rectangle>
```

It works when I use color like red but it wont work with my ImagePath please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Clemens I updated my code with changeing ImageSource to ImagePath but it still seems not to work. After setter sets the value getter is not called can this be the problem? Is this fixable?

Comment: In case that XAML is part of the XAML of the InputBlock UserControl, write `Fill="{Binding ImageBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Take a look at the Output Window, read and understand the error messages, and read the documentation about data binding.

Comment: @Clemens yeah it works now. I am gonna check documentation on this topic is probably needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the source object of the Binding, i.e. the object that owns the source property.

Because that is the UserControl instance, write

```
Fill="{Binding ImageBrush,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

---

People may tell you to set the DataContext of the UserControl instance to itself, e.g. by setting `DataContext = this;` in the constructor. This is however a big mistake, because it prevents that you can use standard DataContext-based Bindings of the properties of your UserControl.